# TFS 2015 XAML Builds migration to Azure DevOps

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We migrated from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps. The XAML builds also ported over to Azure. But we need to migrate them to Azure build pipelines as the XAML builds are still running on On premises TFS Server.  We have hundreds of builds and cant manually create new pipeline for each build one at a time. Can some one help please?

Comment: You're going to have to create new build definitions one way or another. Look at the available REST APIs and figure out how to automate the process. I've done this kind of engagement probably dozens of times and every situation is unique, so no one can give you a simple recipe you can follow.

Comment: Thank you.. I posted answer below..

Comment: There's no reason to migrate all builds from XAML - XAML is still supported. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

XAML builds are still supported with Azure DevOps Service (with some limitations), see [official response from Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/444901/are-xaml-build-really-deprecated-in-azure-devops.html), in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54555245/169672).
We're currently in the process of migrating from TFS to Azure DevOps and we're not planning on upgrading any of our legacy XAML builds (we're creating vNext builds going forward), as they were successfully migrated into Azure.

Comment: Do you remember how you connected your Azure DevOps Server with your XAML build controller?

Comment: I did provide some more details on how we set those up in my other answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54140943/on-premises-tfs-to-vsts-migration-of-xaml-builds/54555245#54555245
But actually all our XAML builds stopped working in March 2022 when Microsoft deprecated TLS 1.0/1.1, and we're just using the standard Azure DevOps builds. See announcement here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deprecating-weak-cryptographic-standards-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-azure-devops-services/

Comment: Yeah, I saw that answer before, but couldn't figure out how to do the actual configuration. event Chat-GPT failed me here :)

Comment: What have you tried? Did you locally installed the TFS Server version that supports XAML (TFS2015 Update 4.1)? tried to connect it to Azure DevOps Services? more importantly - what is the cost of migrating to new builds?

Comment: We've got a few critical complicated XAML builds that will take a while to migrate, and that's what stopping us from migrating to Azure DevOps Server. seems a shame to wait for upgrading TFS 2018 because of this.
What I tried: I Installed the 2015 server locally, but couldn't see where it can be configured to be connected to Azure DevOps Server (which is also installed locally, on another machine)

Comment: Understood... unfortunately I don't remember the details, but basically you use the TFS 2015 as build controller and point it to the other server if I remember correctly
Just another point - we use Azure DevOps Service, the cloud version, so there may be a difference. You should probably reach out to Microsoft if you haven't already

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a way ( I am not done yet)..
we can call the api and export the build defs into json files 
Use the Json files to port them over to the new Build defs. (Porting involves creating new builds programatically and using Azure Api ..  + the data from Json files we just exported).